# Send Binary File via socket

Tags: c#-4.0

I have been trying to send a binary file through TCP socket, my file lenght is 5Mo what i'm receiving is only 1Mo, the received file contains many missing parts, i don't understand why, i have tried to split the binary file into 5 part of 1Mo and i sent the first part (1 Mo) the file received is only 255!!! please can someone explain why? and is there an efficient way to send this type of file?

this is the code i am using,it is containing three parts: browsing the binary file/open socket for sending the file/ sending the file:

```
private void senduimage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
string inpath = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Bureau\\uImage";
 FileStream fs = new FileStream(inpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);  
if (!user.clientSocket_NewSocket.Connected)
{

Socket clientSocket_NewSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
 user.clientSocket_NewSocket = clientSocket_NewSocket;
 try
  {
    System.IAsyncResult _NewSocket = user.clientSocket_NewSocket.BeginConnect(ip_address, NewSocket.Transceiver_TCP_Port, null, null);
    bool successNewSocket = _NewSocket.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(2000, true);
  }
 byte[] buff = null;
 BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
 string inpath = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Bureau\\uImage"
 long numbytes = new FileInfo(inpath).Length;
 buff = br.ReadBytes((int)numbytes);
 user.clientSocket_NewSocket.Send(buff);
}
```

}

any help will be welcome,, thanks :)

---

i have tried the send to file that you proposed to me , but it gave me an exception saying that this operation can not be done with not connected sockets, this is the code i used:

```
01  private void senduimage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
02          {
03              
06             
07              if (!user.clientSocket_NewSocket.Connected)
08              {
09   
10                  Socket clientSocket_NewSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
11                  user.clientSocket_NewSocket = clientSocket_NewSocket;
12                   
13              }
14               
15              System.IAsyncResult _NewSocket = user.clientSocket_NewSocket.BeginConnect(ip_address, NewSocket.Transceiver_TCP_Port, null, null);
16              bool successNewSocket = _NewSocket.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(2000, true);
17              if (successNewSocket)
18              {
19                  string fileName = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Bureau\\uImage";
20                  user.clientSocket_NewSocket.SendFile(fileName);
21                  user.clientSocket_NewSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
22                  user.clientSocket_NewSocket.Close();
23              }
```

any suggestions please?

Comment: ok, thank you for the information, any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SendFile() method of the socket or you can try sending data in a while loop. In while loop send some data like 1KB or something like that.